# Passing multiple variables to javascript function from onclick link

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to pass variables to a js function:

```
<script>

(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/de_DE/all.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

// async init once loading is done
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId: 1234567890987, status: false});
};

function gogogo(data) {

    FB.ui({
        method: 'feed',
        link: data.url,
        picture: data.picture,
        name: data.title,
        //caption: data.caption,
        description: data.description
    });
}
```

Gets in here and displayed all except description:

```
<%= link_to image_tag('icons/social-fb.png'),'#', :onclick=>"gogogo({ url:'#{request.original_url}',title:'#{content.title}',picture:'#{PICTURE_PATH+content.tg_medias.first.media.url(:big)}', description:'#{content.description}' }) ;return false;" %>
```

content.description is not working.. 
Thanks

Comment: Please don't update your question to remove the original problem. It makes my answer irrelevant and removes the resource from others who may have the same problem in the future. Please accept my answer if it solves your original problem, and open a new question now that you're having a different problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass a javascript object as the argument to the `gogogo` function. Try replacing

```
gogogo(data=(url:'#{request.original_url}',url:'#{content.title}'));
```

with

```
gogogo({url:'#{request.original_url}',title:'#{content.title}'});
```

I'm assuming the fact that your argument's two keys were both `url` was a typo.

Comment: Thanks.. yes a typo..Now i have: <%= link_to image_tag('icons/social-fb.png'),'#', :onclick=>"gogogo({ url:'#{request.original_url}',title:'#{content.title}',caption:'#{content.title}', picture:'#{PICTURE_PATH+content.tg_medias.first.media.url(:big)}', desc:'#{sanitize(content.description)}' });return false;" %> .  All is working, but not content.description. It seems that text must be handled different..or html tags may be not allowed..

Comment: Sorry, I don't know ruby, so I might be of limited use. What shows up in the browser as the `desc` value? i.e. what does ruby return for `#{sanitize(content.description)}`?

Comment: description p.a.: <p>hello world</p>, sanitize makes sure that there is no 'bad code' in it..when I supply this value the popup does not open and I get: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token in the console

Comment: As long as the string is quoted in the javascript object, that's a perfectly acceptable value (html in an object value is no problem). Can you please post the full generated html markup of the tag? There must be something invalid in there.

Comment: The current code ist displayed on the top...Thanks for checking

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding, your current error is a javascript error, so it would be easiest to debug by seeing the *generated html*, not the ruby source.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136555/discussion-between-nvioli-and-werner).

Answer (score 0):

I have done this in my many projects. So I will suggest you following approach.

- Put an id on the link
- add an script tag in the view

> Add following code in a script tag in your view

```
$(document).ready(function($){
    $("a#id_of_that_link").on('click', function(e){
        gogogo(#{@prepared_data.to_json}, true, #{@anything_else.to_json});
    });
});
```

Now you will get these params at your function.
Let me know If you have any confusion.